# Input to list and operate on it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started with Python (3.x), and while it is fairly easy to pick up, I'm trying to learn how to work with lists.

I've written a small program which asks for the amount of numbers to input, then asks for the numbers. Where I'm scratching my head a little is here;

```
    t += numList[int(i)]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

I'm sure it's obvious to someone else. I thought that lists used an integer index? And that referencing that index would return the contents?
(I have a C++ background, so I'm finding that some things don't work how I thought they would).

Full program here;

```
runLoop = True
numList = []

def avg():
    t = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(numList):
        t += numList[i]
        i += 1
    print (" total is " + str(t))

while runLoop == True:
    maxLen = int(input("Average Calculator : "
                       "Enter the amount of number "
                       "to calculate for"))
    while len(numList) < maxLen:
        numList.append(input("Enter number : "))

    avg()

    if input("Would you like to run again? (y/n) ") == "n":
        quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Type casting:**

Type casting is missing in following statement

`numList.append(input("Enter number : "))`

e.g.  Use `input()` method for **python 3.x**

```
>>> a = raw_input("Enter number:")
Enter number:2
>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>
>>> b = int(a)
>>> type(b)
<type 'int'>
>>>
```

2. **Add Integer type variable with Integer type variable:** This will raise exception at `t += numList[i]` statement because we are adding integer variable with string variable, it is not allowed.

e.g.

```
>>> 1 + "1"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
>>>
```

3. No need to check length of list in while loop `while i < len(numList):`. We can iterate directly on list.

e.g.

```
>> numList = [1,4,10]
>>> total = 0
>>> for i in numList:
...    total += i
... 
>>> print total
15
>>>
```

4. **Inbuilt sum() function:** We can use inbuilt function `sum()` to get from list.

e.g.

```
>>> numList = [1,4,10]
>>> sum(numList)
15
>>>
```

5. **Exception handling:** It is good programming to handle exception on user input. Use exception handling during type casting. If user enters any non integer number and we are type casting that non integer string into integer that time python interpreter raise ValueError.

e.g.

```
>>> try:
...   a = int(raw_input("Enter Number:"))
... except ValueError:
...   print "Wrong number. Enters only digit."
... 
Enter Number:e
Wrong number. Enters only digit.
```

Comment: @user229050 : Welcome, If you have any query, you can free to ask on stackoverflow or  I can be reached anytime via email at vivekbsable@gmail.com, for my skype id: vivek.igp.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Vivik for the answer.
I have now adjusted my simple program and solved the issue I had; code as follows.

```
runLoop = True
numList = []

def avg(workList):
    t = sum(workList)
    print ("Average is " + str(t/len(workList)) )
    print ("Total is " + str(t) )

while runLoop == True:
    maxLen = int(input("Average Calculator : "
                       "Enter the amount of number "
                       "to calculate for : "))
    while len(numList) < maxLen:
        numList.append(int(input("Enter number : ")))

    avg(numList)

    if input("Would you like to run again? (y/n) ") == "n":
        quit()
```

I can see that I could quite easily shorten it down to;

```
runLoop = True
numList = []

while runLoop == True:
    maxLen = int(input("Average Calculator: Enter the amount of number to calculate for : "))

    while len(numList) < maxLen:
        numList.append(int(input("Enter number : ")))

    print ("Average is " + str(sum(numList)/len(numList)) )
    print ("Total is " + str(sum(numList)) )

    if input("Would you like to run again? (y/n) ") == "n":
        quit()
```

But, the point of my little !/pointless exercise was to explore the relationships of lists, input to lists, and printing lists.

Cheers!

Comment: I am not getting what ` relationships of lists, input to lists, and printing lists. ` Can you give example ??